# How to change the Partial Cut Width of a Zebra KR203 printer?

Tags: printer, kiosk, zebra-printer

i need to change the Partial Cut Width so the printer doesn't cut all the paper when finishing to print something, i tried to do this in the printer properties but all the options are locked and i don't know why. Here is an image.

[image: Printer configuration]

Anyone know how to unlock this option or if there is another way to change the Partial Cut Width?

Edit: That option doesn't appear on the Printing Defaults section.

[image: Printer preferences]

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the printer is set up via a server, and you want the default setting changed. In that case, on the server, go to Printer Properties and click the Advanced tab. Now click the Printing Defaults button and adjust the setting.

[image]

If you want the default setting to stay at 0, but give the user the option to change it, then do the following. On the server, go to Printer Properties and click the Security tab. Give the user (or Everyone) Manage permissions on the printer.

Comment: Hi, on the first thing that you said, i go to the Printing defaults but the Partial Cut Width option doesn't appear. And in the second thing, I already had all the permissions on the printer, so that didn't work neither.

Comment: If it appears in Printing Properties (as per your image) then it will also appear in Printing Defaults. But my comment about Opciones avanzadas was wrong. I have now deleted it.

Comment: No, it doesn't appear on the Printing Defaults, see the photo that i added to the question.

Comment: Your new image shows Printing Preferences (Preferencias), not Printing Defaults. Printing Properties has tabs for Ports, Sharing and "Advanced". The Printing Defaults button shows when you click the Advanced tab. I have added an image of my printer's properties.